# How do I get name and label of fields in user profiles?

Tags: 7, entities

I want to get the list of fields added to user profiles(listed here admin/config/people/accounts/fields). I need machine name and label of each field. How do I get them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`field_info_instances()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7) function to get that data:

```
$fields = field_info_instances('user', 'user');

foreach ($fields as $field) {
  $machine_name = $field['field_name'];
  $label = $field['label'];
}
```

Comment: For anyone that want instance for single field, please use:
`field_info_instance('user', 'field_available_date', 'user')`

Comment: What's the third argument, `user`, for? The manual only shows two arguments: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7 `field_info_instances($entity_type = NULL, $bundle_name = NULL)`

Comment: Assuming you're referring to sobi3ch's comment @user1359, that's a different function (no 's' on the end)